# How can I encrypt just the values of a .env file?

Tags: encryption, environment-variables, key, config, secret-key

I need the names of the keys for a build pipeline in GitHub actions, the values of the keys encrypted in the repo but decrypted in my local environment.
Example:
I need the .env file like this (decrypted) in my local environment:

ACCESS_KEY = mykeysecret123

ANOTHER_KEY = key2secret

[.env-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN1V3.png)

And like this (encrypted) in the GitHub repo:

ACCESS_KEY = f4d5dfa6f5da4f6as5dfsdhgzxcvr4

ANOTHER_KEY = dhjdujfk5f64f8ghjdj5j56jhjh4jhf

[.env-file-encrypted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HCof.png)

Very similar to what [transcrypt](https://github.com/elasticdog/transcrypt) does, but transcypt encrypts the whole file, and I need the key names of the file to be not-encrypted, so when the build runs in Github actions it can find the names of the variables. The build does not need the actual secret values. It's failing becase I have a config file with:

```
import { ACCESS_KEY, ANOTHER_KEY} from 'react-native-dotenv'
```

And when the build looks for those names in the .env file, it can't find them if the file is encrypted with transcrypt or git-crypt or any other encrypting tool that encrypts the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice tool by Mozilla that encrypts only the values and not the keys of your secret file
https://github.com/mozilla/sops

Follow the detailed tutorial video here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2PRhxphH2w

Comment: Not useful there is less information about env file encryption.

Answer (score 2):

react-native-dotenv maintainer here! I took a look at your screenshots and I'm noticing a couple issues:

1. Make sure to remove all spaces in the `.env` file around the `=`, e.g. `ACCESS_KEY=f4d5dfa6f5da4f6as5dfsdhgzxcvr4`.
2. you need to do `import { ACCESS_KEY, ANOTHER_KEY } from '@env'`